# Do classes which extend other classes inherit the same constructor?

Tags: php, oop

For instance...

if I have a Module class:

```
class Module{

  var $page;

  function Module($page){
    $this->page = $page;
  }
}
```

and then a specific News module class:

```
class News extends Module {
  function aFunction(){
    return $this->page->id;
  }
}
```

can I instantiate News like this:

```
$page = new Page();
$news = new News($page);
```

or would I have to do this:

```
$page = new Page();
$news = new News();
$news->page = $page;
```

Thank you.

PS: I'm quite new to OOP php, so bear with me lol. I've gone from procedural php to objective-c and now back to objective php. :p Its very difficult trying to compare each to the other.

Comment: Add a `get` method to the subclass that returns `$page`. What happens?

Comment: Why dont you just test both cases yourself and see which work? Then you can go to the docs and confirm that that is the expected behaviour. I don't have much php oop experience, although i seriously doubt there is constructor inheritance

Comment: Davin, thanks for the comment. I've looked in the documentation and have my own opinions as to what will "work" and what wont. I'm just interested not only in what people have to say, but also tips and alternatives that I might glean from people. Also, in iphone programming if a class method isn't found in the main class the request is passed up the class chain till a method is found and executed. So I want to know if there is a similar feature in php. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they inherit the constructor. This is something you can easily test yourself. For instance:

```
class Foo {
  function __construct() {
    echo "foo\n";
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}
```

When you run:

```
$bar = new Bar();  // echoes foo
```

However, if you define a custom constructor for your class, it will not call Foo's constructor. Make sure to call `parent::__construct()` in that case.

```
class Baz extends Foo {
  function __construct() {
    echo "baz ";
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

$baz = new Baz();  // echoes baz foo
```

All of this is true for your old-style constructors, too (name of class vs `__construct`).

Comment: aha... thats exactly what I wanted to know. :) thank you. So if I don't define it it will move up the class chain until it encounters a __construct() method. :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to specify a constructor for `News`, `function News($page) {...}` which would call the parent constructor like this: `parent::Module($page)`. You're trying to encapsulate `$page`, and accessing it directly defeats this purpose.

Comment: Thank you kubi, the only thing is the reason I want to subclass the Module class is to cut down on the amount of rewritten code. I know its only one line, but lets say in the future I change the constructor method of Module, I didn't really want to have to go through EVERY subclass and change their constructor methods too.

Comment: Well, in PHP, and other OO languages, like Java, C#, or C++ you have to call the parent constructor explicitly. It's a small price to pay. Also, as a side note, in PHP5 you should define the constructor using __construct: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but the last piece of code would look very bizarre in any OOP language I know. In OOP languages the constructor of News would implicitly or explicitly call the constructor of Module.

Comment: What? lol in iphone programming you're always calling `[object setProperty:anotherProperty];` so I don't think the last piece of code is *that* strange, but I see what you're saying. So I have to explicitly call it, like kubi says?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should use `__construct()` instead of the name of the class as the constructor as this is more modular.

As with any other OOP language, the constructor of a child class is inherited by its parent, so your first example will indeed work.

One thing to keep in mind, though, is that a parent constructor is not implicitly called by the parent.  So if you define a constructor in `News`, the first example won't work anymore unless you have the News constructor handle `$page` on its own, or call `parent::__construct($page);`

Another issue is that the encapsulation the classes provide is violated by `$page` being public.  The `var` keyword is a remnant of PHP 4, and you should declare `$page` as private.  It should be visible to and handled by only the Module class.  For instance, why does News need `aFunction`?

Comment: Right, so you're saying $page (in the Module class) should be private? Will it still be accessible from within the News class? News needs aFunction because its going to go to the db and get the latest news out for the specific page we're on. If there is a Content class which extends Module then it might get the specific block of content that is on the page etc ad infinitum. So each subclass of Module will need access to the $page variable. The reason for Module is to standardise certain aspects of all Modules, for instance the collecting and storing of the $page object.

Comment: What do you mean __construct() is more modular by the way? I don't really understand how the two differ. I realise construct() is a php5 standard, but why have they changed it? Also, using the name of the class as a construct is backwards compatible if anyone were to call class::__construct() whereas the other way round would fail if I defined a __construct() method and it was called with class::class(). So what are the advantages to using __construct?

Comment: The advantage of using __construct is that you can rename the class at any time without having to alter the constructor.  $page would not be accessible to News if it were private, but the question is why News needs access to $page.  I'm not a fan of protected members, but you could at least use that.  I'm also not sure what you mean in your example.  Constructors cannot be static.

Comment: Ah you see, modules provide differing functionality to my overall script. So therefore they all need access to the same dataset but to provide different outcomes. News needs to know what page its dealing with so it can show the right content. An adverts module might need to know what page its on so it can show the relevant adverts etc. Thats why they need access to the $page variable. But I don't want to duplicate all instances of this, which is why I'll be subclassing $module. :)

Comment: ps. your reasoning is quite good for the __construct method. However if I rename the class moving 2 lines below it and copying and pasting the new name isn't going to be that difficult. However, I guess then when you've got that method called from other classes it may be a bit of a pain, although if you change the class name you'll also have to go through and change all instances of `new ClassName` to `new OtherName` anyway... (and the same for extends) :/

Answer (score 0):

you can inherit the attributs of another class for example the italienChef inherited the makeChiken from the class Chef so when we run it it gives us // the chef makes chiken

```php
class Chef{

    function makeChiken(){
        echo "the chef makes chiken <br>";
    }
}

class ItalienChef extends Chef{
   function makePasta(){
    echo "the chef makes pasta";
   }
   
$italienchef = new ItalienChef();
$italienchef-> makeChiken();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was about the constructor